# How do I get telemetry into a Windows 10 UWP App?

Tags: azure, uwp, azure-application-insights

The Azure documentation for App Insights doesn't appear to have fresh articles relating to Windows 10 UWP Apps specifically. This appears to be endemic throughout all services (Notification Hub, Mobile Apps, Azure AD, etc.). So far I have found only references to Windows 8/8.1 Universal apps. I'm not sure how applicable they are but some code snippets do seem to compile at least.

My problem is that I have just setup a new App Insights instance for a 'WindowsStore App'. This is intended for a Windows 10 UWP app.

In my app, I have done the following:

1. Ingested the nuget package for App Insights which has created an ApplicationInsights.config file.
2. Updated the Instrumentation Key with the one from my WindowsStore App Insights Instance in the Azure Portal.
3. Added Internet (Client) capability in application manifest.
4. Created a static TelemetryClient that I use throughout all my Views / View Models.

   ```
   private static TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
   public static TelemetryClient Telemetry
   {
       get { return telemetry; }
   }
   ```
5. Updated the WindowsAppInitializer to include several WindowsCollectors.

   ```
           Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
           WindowsCollectors.Metadata | 
           WindowsCollectors.Session | 
           WindowsCollectors.PageView | 
           WindowsCollectors.UnhandledException
           );
   ```
6. Added an event handler within App.xaml.cs for Unhandled Exception and call TelemetryClient.TrackException on the exception.

   ```
   private void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
   {
       ViewModelDispatcher.Telemetry.TrackException(e.Exception);
   }
   ```
7. Added TelemetryClient.TrackPageViews to OnNavigatedTo overrides in my views.

But so far, after doing all that, my App Insights dashboard in the Azure Portal is showing zip, zilch, nada. :\

This makes me think one of two things is going on. Either I am missing some critical piece of this recipe or I'm still within the refresh window for the App Insights Dashboard.

Comment: hypothetically you don't need #6 since you had WindowsCollectors.UnhandledException already set in the initializeasync call.

Comment: but in my app config file is not adding.. how to add it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to include your instrumentation key to the call of InitializeAsync?
I'm using the following code at the constructor of App class.

```
    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
                    "YOURINST-RUME-NTAT-IONK-EY012345678",
                    WindowsCollectors.Metadata |
                    WindowsCollectors.PageView |
                    WindowsCollectors.Session |
                    WindowsCollectors.UnhandledException);
```

I haven't confirmed the current specs (yes...the documentation of ApplicationInsight is an labyrinth :( ), but from AI v1.0, you have not to include your instrumentation key to your applicationinsight.config. Instead of it, you can specify the key with the call of initializer.

Comment: That worked. I'm still not sure why it didn't pull it from the ApplicationInsights.config though. :)

Comment: if the config file isn't set as content and copy if newer, it doesn't end up deployed to the device, so the sdk can't find it at runtime.

Comment: (and updated my answer as well, there's another reason why the sdk might not see your real key in the config file, even if it is set to content+copy)

Answer (score 2):

Recently found this (i work on the AI team and it still happened to me!).

If you *manually* added the `applicationinsights.config` file, make sure it is set to "Content" and "Copy if newer" in the project settings.  If it isn't, then the sdk can't find the instrumentation key at runtime, since the applicationinsights.config file didn't get deployed to the device.

**Update 1/11/2016:** i just learned of another issue that can cause this:  comments in the xml file that look like xml tags.

If your config file has any comments of the form:

```
<!-- <InstrumentationKey>anything</InstrumentationKey> -->
```

Or

```
<!-- 
Learn more about Application Insights configuration with ApplicationInsights.config here: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513840

Note: If not present, please add <InstrumentationKey>Your Key</InstrumentationKey> to the top of this file.
 -->
```

(Like is common in examples you might have gotten online, or migrating from a previous version of the AI SDK's)

If those comments appear in your config file *before* your real key, then the win10 sdk startup code will find those in the comments instead of your real key.

So if you see debug output that says it is using the literal string "YourKey" instead your actual key, that's the reason.  (The win10 sdk uses a regex to find your key instead of loading system.xml assemblies to parse the file)

Comment: I'm really confused...The App Insights page makes it look like it's only meant for "web apps", not UWP applications. Can we use application insights with our UWP/Xamarin/.NET apps?

Comment: Originally, AI was for "Everything".  and then Microsoft acquired HockeyApp, and then Microsoft acquired Xamarin, etc.  so *now*, the recommendation is that "HockeyApp" is intended for *device* apps and AI is mostly intended for *server/web* apps.  but the HockeyApp SDK can actually be used to send data to Application Insights, etc.  (see https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-integrate-hockeyapp-with-application-insights)  The AI windows sdk is no longer being updated, but the HockeyApp one is, and is compatible with AI.

Comment: @JohnGardner HockeyApp no longer supports UWP as far as I can tell. The page required to setup a UWP app (the preseason page) https://www.hockeyapp.net/preseason Links to visual studio mobile telemetry now and that only supports iOS and Droid currently with UWP support to follow.

Comment: ick.  the hockeyapp packages are up on nuget though: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HockeySDK.UWP/  and the link above lets you send data to AI with their SDKs with my link above.